# A function f on a metric space is uniformly continuous iff for every pair of subsets A, B with d(A, B)=0 implies that d'(f(A), f(B))=0

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

I have a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, where $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ are metric spaces. I need to prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$ iff for all $A, B \subseteq X$ such that $d(A, B)=0$ implies that $d'(f(A), f(B))=0$

Necessity is clear. I can't show the sufficiency. I tried by contradiction. Suppose that $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Then, for some $\epsilon_0$ there are sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $d(a_n, b_n)\rightarrow0$ and $d'(f(a_n), f(b_n))>\epsilon_0$.
Therefore, I defined the sets $A$ and $B$ as the set that contains the $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s respectively. So $d(A,B)=0$. By hypothesis $d'(f(A), f(B))=0$. 
I can't use this fact.

I proved the continuity of the function on $X$, but it's so hard prove the uniform. I can't show this part.

Comment: $d(f[A], f[B]) \ge \varepsilon_0$ can maybe be achieved by picking the $a_n, b_n$ carefully?

Comment: How can I choose "carefully" that sequences? I can't see it.

Comment: I agree with Henno that the way to answer this question is to choose $a_n,b_n$ carefully. That is in such a way that for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ $d(f(a_n),f(b_m)) \ge \varepsilon_0$. I believe that such a careful way exists but I am having trouble justifying that belief.

Comment: I proved the continuity; using the fact that a function is continuous on $X$ If and only if for every set $S\subseteq X$ the image of its closure  is contained in the closure of its image.

Comment: What is $d(A,B)$?

Comment: @Olivier I'd imagine $d(A,B):=\inf\{d(a,b):a\in A \land b\in B\}$.

Comment: @Olivier K.Power is correct.

Comment: thanks to everyone. It is a nice exercise.